# Django - How to display specific text after the discount is no longer valid

Tags: django, python-3.x

I'm working on a project and I want to know how to display the product 'name' and its 'price' when the validity of the 'discount_price' expires and as long as the 'discount_price' is valid, I would like to display the product 'name', 'price' and 'discount_price'.

**models.py:**

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime

class Products(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=60)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/', default='photos/none.png',
                              null=True, blank=True)
    description=models.TextField()
    price=models.FloatField()
    discount_price = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    valid_from = models.DateTimeField(('Valid from'), default=datetime.now)
    valid_until = models.DateTimeField(('Valid until'), blank=True, null=True)
    stock=models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

**my template, index.html:**

```
{% extends "./base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}

<h3 style="text-align:center"> Product list: </h3>
  {% for product in products %}
       <div class="products">
           <div class="item">
               <table >
                   {% if product.discount %}
                       <tr><td> <a class="products" href ="{% url 'entry' produs.id %}">
                           {{products.name}} {{product.discount|cut:".0"}} {{product.price|cut:".0"}}</a>
                   {% else %}
                       <tr><td><a class="products" href ="{% url 'entry' product.id %}"> {{product.name}}  {{product.price|cut:'.0'}} </a>
                   {% endif %}
               </table>
            </div>
       </div>
  {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a property that returns if the discount is still valid:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class Products(models.Model):
    # …

    @property
    def active_discount(self):
        now = timezone.now()
        return self.discount_price and self.valid_from <= now and (self.valid_until is None or now <= self.valid_until)
```

Then you thus can use that in the template:

```
{% if product.active_discount %}
    <tr><td> <a class="products" href ="{% url 'entry' produs.id %}">
        {{products.name}} {{product.discount|cut:".0"}} (pret intreg: {{product.price|cut:".0"}})</a>
{% else %}
    <tr><td><a class="products" href ="{% url 'entry' product.id %}"> {{product.name}}  {{product.price|cut:'.0'}} </a>
{% endif %}
```